# Collection of different types in JSON

Tags: json

I have 3 different schema - **s1, s2 & s3** , and want to use these schema objects from parent object **P**. Basically, collection of different types of objects but not able to find a way to create JSON spec for this case. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do you need a spec?  It's perfectly legit JSON, even if you can't define an overarching schema.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but is this what you're looking for?

```
{
    "ParentSchema": {
        "ChildSchema1": {
            "title": "S1",
            "description" : "Schema1"
        },
        "ChildSchema2": {
            "title": "S2",
            "description" : "Schema2"
        },
        "ChildSchema3": {
            "title": "S3",
            "description" : "Schema3"
        }
    }
}
```